How can I work around the issues and obtain a proper computing environment?
I have been working on machine learning and neural network training for some of my projects. My supervisor gave me some Linux computers that are at least a decade old and equipped with GeForce GTX 780 GPUs.
There are multiple problems with these Linux computers.

Because of some strange reason, these computers automatically shuts down and go offline at least every two months. Someone has to go inside the server room and manually start them, bypassing some BIOS-related issues. Suppose I am working on Saturday evening at 6 pm and the machine abruptly shuts down. I need to wait until Monday morning, go to the faculty building, and then manually start the machine.

Those old GPUs have small memories. As a result, they cannot handle even medium datasets (e.g., 1 million samples and nine features).

These machines are behind a gatekeeper computer. So, it is very tedious to upload and download files from and to those machines on my laptop. So, what I do is first upload my files to another remote machine, and then I transfer those files to those GPU-equipped computers.


I requested that my supervisor provide me a dedicated machine equipped with powerful GPUs. However, he gave me another old machine. I set up Windows 10 on that machine and installed GPUs. However, the machine was slow, and I could not install the latest versions of the Tensorflow library that can work with that GPU and CUDA. When I requested that he give me a new machine, he said he could not. If I want to have a new machine, I should apply for research grants from government agencies, etc.
Another problem is that my supervisor is a pathological liar. So, arguing with him is like trying to nail jelly to the wall. No matter what I say, he slithers like an eel.
Now, my question is, how can I work around these issues and obtain a proper computing environment to train my neural networks?

Why are you working for someone you consider to be a pathological liar, and who does not support your work?

@Anonymous, Because I need to finish my PhD.

During my PhD, I had to buy myself a good computer (2,000€) otherwise I would not progress. Those GPUs are useless. By the way what you say about VRAM being too small for datasets is wrong. Nobody keeps the entire dataset in VRAM - you keep the model, a batch and activations, not the entire dataset. In any case, that GPU is useless, you need to buy yourself a proper computer or you will not progress. I had to do the same myself.

@RicardoCruz, Kindly post this comment as an answer. I will accept that.

@RicardoCruz, How about Colab Pro+ or Amazon AWS?

@user366312 I have once glanced at the numbers that AWS charges and did some back-of-the-envelope calculations, and it seemed to be cheaper to just buy a GPU. If you rent for $1/minute and you use a single GPU for 8h per days, then you burn $1500 in around 6 months. For $600 you can buy a good 12GB GPU (an A2000 or a RTX 3080 - maybe A2000 is better for neural networks). For most computer vision work they are very good (unless you work with something very intensive like NeRFs). I don't know about NLP/LLM, I don't work in that area, maybe that area requires more VRAM because of transformers.

Cloud Computing/GPU As A Service
One very real possibility is Cloud Computing, or GPUaaS.  But it's going to come with a very large caveat at the end.
My firm opinion is, even if your advisor were dripping with generous funding, you don't want to be managing this stuff yourself.  You want someone with real expertise and real money to set this stuff up for you and a few hundred of your closest buddies, and just give you terminal and Jupyter Lab access to little slices of it.
In 2024, this is not hard to find.  Many variants exist:

Some (maybe many, now?) universities will provide this, either at department levels or as the university itself.

Some National Labs, in the United States, provide this and partner with universities or industry.  I would be shocked if this idea were not replicated in other nations.

The National Science Foundation (again, in the United States) has some initiatives like the Chameleon Cloud.

Private companies abound, from Amazon on down, providing this sort of thing.


There are surely others, but that should get you started.
Here's the big caveat:  Those systems come with some downsides.
The commercial entities are going to charge you money, for instance.  And while my advisor was willing to set me up with some Amazon reimbursements, it sounds like yours won't.  And depending on what you want to do, it can get expensive.  And you shouldn't be paying for this out of pocket, anyway.
I remember Chameleon Cloud being difficult to schedule time on, but that was a while ago, maybe it's changed.
National Labs may have limits on use, or want to you to apply for grants.
University in-house solutions, though... those can be pretty sweet.  Mine was.  I rarely had access to whatever the latest GPUs were, but they were pretty recent.  And I didn't need the very latest and greatest anyway.

Here in Australia, to take another example, most universities have high performance computing facilities of their own and if that isn’t enough, we can apply for resources on the National Computing Infrastructure, which will likely be granted if the project is worthwhile. Another option would be for the supervisor to organise a collaboration with someone at an institution with better HPC resources (e.g., CSIRO). Of course, if the supervisor is indeed a “pathological liar” and known as such, that might be difficult.

@Significance same here (Germany): my university has some HPC resources of its own and there are resources in my case at the state level rather than national level.

If you want to have a new machine, you should apply for research grants from government agencies, etc...
(It seems your advisor already gave you the correct answer)

Until then?     also, those grants are competitive and not guaranteed.

@user366312 yes, grants are competitive and not guaranteed. I imagine that is why your supervisor cannot simply buy you a new computer — he’d need a grant to pay for it. The other answer gives some other good ideas, but without knowing your country, it’s hard to say exactly what your options are.

@Significance, I better not reveal the country.

@DanielHatton one would hope so, yes. If the OP is early in their PhD, not having this support would be a good reason to change supervisor or quit. If later in the PhD, perhaps the supervisor failed to anticipate the need?

@user366312 the information on your profile suggests an interest in one particular country, so see Maarten Buis’ comment on that other answer.

@DanielHatton It is possible OP's PI is a subject-matter expert in something else, and doesn't know the computational requirements for OP's project.
